# Is there a way to bake volume density information which is generated from an OSL script?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, volumetrics, osl

I am trying to generate volume density information (e.g. a [mandelbulb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbulb)) from an Open Shader Language script in cycles. This however only works when rendering with a CPU. My GPU is much faster but doesn't support OSL.

I was wondering if I could just generate the volume density and bake/export it similar to how one would bake a smoke simulation.

I could then just load it again and render it with my GPU.